# Bottle-priming post secondary fining?

Tags: beer, carbonation, priming, clarity, finings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cold Crash and Finings](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/cold-crash-and-finings)

As mentioned in [this question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/5007/clarification-for-a-low-flocculating-yeast), I'm anticipating some trouble with a low-flocculating yeast, and one of the suggestions was to use gelatin for fining in the secondary.

I am planning to bottle-condition these beers, and my understanding is that while for bottle conditioning one hopes for about 1,000,000 cells per mL, that finings such as gelatin and isinglass have the ability to bring me down to about 10,000 cells per mL.  One additional piece of information is that this is [a low-flocculating Kolsch yeast](http://www.wyeastlab.com/rw_yeaststrain_detail.cfm?ID=144), so I wonder if the effect will be as significant.

Do I need to worry about having an under-carbonated beer if I use gelatin on a low-flocculating yeast? Would I need to compensate with additional priming sugar, or some fresh yeast, or some other measures?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/3348/678. Moral of the story is you should be fine bottle fermenting after using finings. You may have to wait a little longer though. Perk mentions that it carbonated well, but took "a week or two".